# How to layout 2 StackView of different sizes in a ScrollView

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, autolayout, uistackview

I am trying to fit 2 `stackView` in one `ScrollView`

I decided to create a generic `StackView` that will contain the other two `StackViews` and place it in a `ScrollView`

But my left `StackView` contains 1 item and the second contains 2 items

Code bellow:

```
        let categoryViewsForLeftColumn = categoryViews.split()[0]
        let categoryViewsForRightColumn = categoryViews.split()[1]
        
        let leftColumnStackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: categoryViewsForLeftColumn)
        leftColumnStackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        leftColumnStackView.axis = .vertical
        leftColumnStackView.spacing = 20
        leftColumnStackView.distribution = .fillEqually
        
        let rightColumnStackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: categoryViewsForRightColumn)
        rightColumnStackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        rightColumnStackView.axis = .vertical
        rightColumnStackView.spacing = 20
        rightColumnStackView.distribution = .fillEqually
        
        let generalStackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [leftColumnStackView, rightColumnStackView])
        generalStackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        generalStackView.axis = .horizontal
        generalStackView.spacing = 20
        generalStackView.distribution = .fillEqually
        
        categoriesScrollView.addSubview(generalStackView)
        
        leftColumnStackView.backgroundColor = .green
        rightColumnStackView.backgroundColor = .red
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            generalStackView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: categoriesScrollView.widthAnchor, constant: -10),
            generalStackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: categoriesScrollView.leadingAnchor, constant: 5),
            generalStackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: categoriesScrollView.trailingAnchor, constant: -5),
            generalStackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: categoriesScrollView.topAnchor, constant: 5),
            generalStackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: categoriesScrollView.bottomAnchor, constant: -5)
        ])
```

result bellow:

[image: result]

I expect items to be the same size

I was trying to post 2 StackView to ScrollView

code bellow:

```
        categoriesScrollView.addSubview(leftColumnStackView)
        categoriesScrollView.addSubview(rightColumnStackView)
        
        leftColumnStackView.backgroundColor = .green
        rightColumnStackView.backgroundColor = .red
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            leftColumnStackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: categoriesScrollView.leadingAnchor, constant: 5),
            leftColumnStackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: categoriesScrollView.centerXAnchor, constant: -5),
            leftColumnStackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: categoriesScrollView.topAnchor, constant: 5),
            leftColumnStackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: categoriesScrollView.bottomAnchor, constant: -5),
            
            rightColumnStackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: categoriesScrollView.centerXAnchor, constant: 5),
            rightColumnStackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: categoriesScrollView.trailingAnchor, constant: -5),
            rightColumnStackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: categoriesScrollView.topAnchor, constant: 5),
            rightColumnStackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: categoriesScrollView.bottomAnchor, constant: -5)
        ])
```

But it only got worse

result bellow:

[image: second result]

The result I want to achieve:

[image: current result]

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Comment: Use a collection view

Comment: If there is no solution, I will, but I still wanted to understand how to do this with ScrollView. Why the left StackView stretches to fit the right when it is completely independent of it, I can't figure it out ...

Comment: @Vladislav - this can certainly be done without a collection view, but your question is confusing. In your images showing what you have done, and in your description, there should be ONE view on the Left, and TWO views on the Right... but in your *"result I want to achieve"* image, your have TWO views on the Left, and ONE view on the Right?

Comment: @DonMag In fact, it doesn't matter how many views there are on the left and right. The most important thing is that there are not equal numbers of them. The last picture is taken from the interface rendering service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create a "grid" like that *without* using a collection view (and there are many good reasons not to), you can do it with stack views.

However, instead of think in terms of a horizontal stack view with two vertical "column" stack views, think about a vertical stack view with "rows" of horizontal stack views.

Here's a quick example...

First, a custom view with rounded sides, an image view and a label:

```
class PillView: UIView {
    
    let imgView = UIImageView()
    let label = UILabel()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    func commonInit() {
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        imgView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        addSubview(imgView)
        addSubview(label)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            imgView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 16.0),
            imgView.topAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualTo: topAnchor, constant: 12.0),
            imgView.bottomAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualTo: bottomAnchor, constant: -12.0),
            imgView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor),
            imgView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 36.0),
            imgView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imgView.widthAnchor),
            
            label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            label.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: -8.0),
            label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imgView.trailingAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            label.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -16.0),

        ])
        layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
        layer.borderWidth = 1
    }
    
    override var bounds: CGRect {
        get { return super.bounds }
        set(newBounds) {
            super.bounds = newBounds
            layer.cornerRadius = newBounds.size.height / 2.0
        }
    }

}
```

Now, a sample controller:

```
class SampleViewController: UIViewController {
    
    let numViews: Int = 5
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let outerVerticalStack = UIStackView()
        outerVerticalStack.axis = .vertical
        outerVerticalStack.spacing = 20
        outerVerticalStack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        view.addSubview(outerVerticalStack)
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            outerVerticalStack.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            outerVerticalStack.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            outerVerticalStack.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),
        ])
        
        var j: Int = 0
        while j < numViews {
            let rowStack = UIStackView()
            rowStack.axis = .horizontal
            rowStack.spacing = 20
            rowStack.distribution = .fillEqually
            
            let v = PillView()
            if j == 2 {
                v.label.text = "View \(j)\ntwo lines"
            } else {
                v.label.text = "View \(j)"
            }
            if let img = UIImage(systemName: "\(j).square.fill") {
                v.imgView.image = img
            }
            rowStack.addArrangedSubview(v)
            
            j += 1
            
            if j < numViews {
                let v = PillView()
                v.label.text = "View \(j)"
                if let img = UIImage(systemName: "\(j).square.fill") {
                    v.imgView.image = img
                }
                rowStack.addArrangedSubview(v)
            } else {
                let v = UIView()
                rowStack.addArrangedSubview(v)
            }
            
            j += 1
            
            outerVerticalStack.addArrangedSubview(rowStack)
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

The result looks like this:

[image]